# Why is undefined being printed on console

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here, I have two functions exactly the same
1)

```
  function al() {
    return 
    {   
        bar: "hello"
    };
}

console.log(al())
```

While running this on node this is printing, undefined
While the same code, with diff bracket level, return the output
2)

```
function al() {
    return {   
        bar: "hello"
    };
}

console.log(al())
```

Please run on node.
Version 10.x

Comment: I didnt know how to search that :-(, really tried searching first

Comment: the console warning should've been a clue :p

Comment: Yup ,it was :-(